# GraphQL java: Throwing exceptions when request has unused variables

Tags: java, graphql, graphql-java

Let's say I have a request payload with a variables map and a query. Does `graphql-java` have any out-of-the-box mechanisms that I can use to detect unused variables in the payload?

For example:

```
type Query { hello : String! } # this just resolves to "hello world"
```

When the user sends in `{foo: 42}` as the `variables` in the request payload, I want to throw an error (say`IllegalArgumentException`).

Edit: Answers/comments on how to implement this without any out-of-the-box mechanisms are also welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Before executing the query , use `Parser` to parse the query into `Document` which is an object representation of the query.The variables defined in the query can be accessed by looking its `OperationDefinition` --> `VariableDefinition` instance. Then comparing them with the variables in the request payload.

As a bonus ,as the graphql-java engine will parse and validate the query for each query execution and this process can be somewhat time consuming, to avoid parsing and validate it twice, you can use [PreparsedDocumentProvider](https://www.graphql-java.com/documentation/master/execution/)